# Windows batch file syntax using exclamation mark

Tags: windows, batch-file

While checking the details of the axis2server.bat file in Axis2 binary distribution I see one of the line containing text something like:

```
FOR %%c in ("%AXIS2_HOME%\lib\*.jar") DO set AXIS2_CLASS_PATH=!AXIS2_CLASS_PATH!;%%c
```

What does the part below with 2 exclamation marks mean?

```
!AXIS2_CLASS_PATH!
```

Names with in % mean variables, not sure what ! mark mean in a batch file.

Comment: Because of the way variable expansion works, see http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php

Comment: @AlexK. thanks it helped. If you could please add an reply I would like to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you `enable delayed expansion` and `change` or `set` a variable within a loop then the `!variable!` syntax allows you to use the variable within the loop.

A drawback is that `!` becomes a poison character for delayed expansion.

Comment: That answers the question, but could you expand on this a bit? Maybe a simple example?

Answer (score 7):

As foxidrive mentioned, this is related to `delayed expansion`. You can find more information by running `help set` in a cmd prompt, which has the following explanation:

```
Finally, support for delayed environment variable expansion has been
added.  This support is always disabled by default, but may be
enabled/disabled via the /V command line switch to CMD.EXE.  See CMD /?

Delayed environment variable expansion is useful for getting around
the limitations of the current expansion which happens when a line
of text is read, not when it is executed.  The following example
demonstrates the problem with immediate variable expansion:

    set VAR=before
    if "%VAR%" == "before" (
        set VAR=after
        if "%VAR%" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
    )

would never display the message, since the %VAR% in BOTH IF statements
is substituted when the first IF statement is read, since it logically
includes the body of the IF, which is a compound statement.  So the
IF inside the compound statement is really comparing "before" with
"after" which will never be equal.  Similarly, the following example
will not work as expected:

    set LIST=
    for %i in (*) do set LIST=%LIST% %i
    echo %LIST%

in that it will NOT build up a list of files in the current directory,
but instead will just set the LIST variable to the last file found.
Again, this is because the %LIST% is expanded just once when the
FOR statement is read, and at that time the LIST variable is empty.
So the actual FOR loop we are executing is:

    for %i in (*) do set LIST= %i

which just keeps setting LIST to the last file found.

Delayed environment variable expansion allows you to use a different
character (the exclamation mark) to expand environment variables at
execution time.  If delayed variable expansion is enabled, the above
examples could be written as follows to work as intended:

    set VAR=before
    if "%VAR%" == "before" (
        set VAR=after
        if "!VAR!" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
    )

    set LIST=
    for %i in (*) do set LIST=!LIST! %i
    echo %LIST%
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to hand over a string containing a "!" as parameter (for imageMagick) and the ! was of course interpreted as syntax which broke my script. The solution was for me, change my string from

```
"Hello World!"
```

to  (just added a ^ before the !):

```
"Hello World^!"
```

I found this trick by reading here: https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php