# What is the difference between % % and ! ! in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, delayedvariableexpansion

What is the difference between these 2 pieces of code in a batch file?

```
set str=!str:%%20= !
```

and

```
set str=%str:%%20= %
```

Comment: it'll just take a few seconds if you've searched for `exclamation mark` instead of `!` which almost no search engines support. Duplicates: [Windows batch file syntax using exclamation mark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22041586/995714), [Difference between %variable% and !variable! in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14354502/995714)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after hours I could find the explanation.
According to this page
[How-to: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes at the Windows command line](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) in the paragraph "Escaping Percents" :

> Escaping Exclamation marks
> When the shell is running in **EnableDelayedExpansion** mode the ! character is used to denote a variable and so must be escaped (twice) if you wish to treat it as a regular character:
>
> ^^!

Comment: This answer does not match the question, it feels like *»where do you live?«* – *»I am 47«*…